# Can I access a Windows 8 crashed partition from Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-8

I had installed Windows 2-3 days before.

On my laptop, there was only one drive. Because I wanted to partition it, I installed application called `easeus partition master`. But because my Windows 8 crashed and I do not have dvd with me, I just want to take a backup of one folder which is very important to me.

I was searching all over the Internet. I installed Ubuntu so that I could access that folder and take a backup.

Is there any was to access that folder for taking a backup?

I googled it and I got couple of results from here as well but with no avail.

**Edit:**

I do not have DVD from where I installed the Windows 8. So it means that I cannot repair it.

I have installed Ubuntu on another partition with the option `Install Ubuntu along with Windows 8` yet I can not access the partition of Windows 8. The error is `Can not mount the partition`.

When I Googled it, I got this found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) and I tried for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/117066).

But I had no luck with it as well.

I just want to copy a folder in C:/ drive where I installed Windows.

Comment: It is not clear what you have done and where you are having problem. Have you made a Live DVD/USB and booted Ubuntu from it by choosing **Try Ubuntu**? Have you looked at your hard drive by using **Gparted** from inside Ubuntu?

Comment: @user68186, i just updated the question, hope it will help you to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means you have put your Windows 8 to hibernate and are trying to mount it in Ubuntu, which gives an error message asking you to shut down windows or mount it as a read-only file-system. Since, your windows has crashed, it won't be possible to shut it down. To manually mount it as a read only file-system type the following on the terminal in ubuntu:
`sudo mount -r <your windows partition on the device> <mount-path>`
in your case, to find out the `windows partition`, if you don't know what it might be, type
`sudo fdisk -l` on the `terminal`. You can make out if you remember the size of the windows partition, it should be of type NTFS. If you have `gparted` installed in ubuntu, you also see the partitions as below:
[image: gparted showing my partitions]
And the `mount path` is usually `/media/user` where `user` is your user-name

For example, if you know your windows partition is on /dev/sda2 and want to mount it on /media/user, just type this on the terminal:

`sudo mount -r /dev/sda2 /media/user`.
This will mount the file system, then go to the folder where it got mounted, and then you can copy the folder you want to by `cp -r <source> <destination>`

Comment: i followed the instruction and it worked as well.. but i want to access the folder exact in `c:` drive.. for example `c:/folder`..

any idea for this?

Comment: Do you know what is the device name for C:/ drive? Is it sda2 or sda1 or something?

Comment: sudo fdisk -l

/dev/sda1--2048--718847--358400--7--HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2--718848--329733807--164507480--7--HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3--329734142--625141759--147703809--5--Extended
/dev/sda5--329734144--616861695--143563776--83--Linux
/dev/sda6--616863744--625141759--4139008--82--Linux swap / Solaris

i had allocated around 155GB for ubuntu and around 165GB for windows

Comment: ok, so sda2 is ur C drive @KuKu

Comment: ok.. so when i do `sudo mount -r /dev/sda2`, output is like this `mount: can't find /dev/sda2 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`.

Comment: actually i neither used ubuntu nor worked with the terminal.. i will appreciate your patience..

Comment: you need to run the command like this:<br>`sudo mount -r /dev/sda2 /media/username/` where username is your username for ubuntu

Comment: hay @Jobin, thaanks a lot.. done with it.. i gone through the your profile. Good to know about you.. good luck

Comment: Happy that it helped you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to install Ubuntu to access directory on disc. Ubuntu installation DVD can act as Live CD as well (**Try Ubuntu** option).

After you start Ubuntu as Live CD, open Nautilus and look for the discs/partitions available in the system.

Comment: yes, i tried that as well in first attempt, when i had no luck with it, then i installed it. I also updated the question.